# Disqus login on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, disqus

I have a problem about disqus login: When signed in the user needs to sign in Disqus again to leave a comment. A much user experience would be if the user only has to sign in once.

I read the document on https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1104796-single-sign-on and follow it. Then i login on my site by wp-login, but disqus ask me login for comment:
[image: Login Disqus]

I must to login twice to leave comment :(

How do users need only log in once?

Thanks.

Comment: if you register as a user in your website then you don't need to create another account but the registration should be from frontend not from wp-admin login section ?

Comment: would you like to show something like this ? http://awesomescreenshot.com/0736102jdc

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj: yes, user login to my site in frontend. I want to know how do when user login by WP account, disqus will login auto for comment with the same account.

Comment: And i dont want to show like  awesomescreenshot.com/0736102jdc, i just want to auto login disqus if user is login on my site.

Comment: please check your setting is it looking something like this  ? http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f26102v82

Comment: yes it's working on my website as your requirement I mean if the user will register or login into they can comment without login again.  please share your website link .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117562/discussion-between-mit-and-raj-kumar-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for this question. And Step by step for anybody need that:

1. First, you need contact to Disqus's support team to enable SSO on your account by this form https://disqus.com/support/?article=contact_SSO.
2. After SSO enable, you need to set up your SSO domain at https://disqus.com/api/sso/ and https://disqus.com/api/applications/ (You can read document in https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on)[image: SSO enable]
3. Paste this code in your theme

```js
<?php
define('DISQUS_SECRET_KEY', '<insert secret key here>');
define('DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY', '<insert public key here>');
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$data = array(
        "id" => $user->data->ID,
        "username" => $user->data->user_login,
        "email" => $user->data->user_email
    );
 
function sb_dsq_hmacsha1($data, $key) {
    $blocksize=64;
    $hashfunc='sha1';
    if (strlen($key)>$blocksize)
        $key=pack('H*', $hashfunc($key));
    $key=str_pad($key,$blocksize,chr(0x00));
    $ipad=str_repeat(chr(0x36),$blocksize);
    $opad=str_repeat(chr(0x5c),$blocksize);
    $hmac = pack(
                'H*',$hashfunc(
                    ($key^$opad).pack(
                        'H*',$hashfunc(
                            ($key^$ipad).$data
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    return bin2hex($hmac);
}
 
$message = base64_encode(json_encode($data));
$timestamp = time();
?>
<script>
    /**
     *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
     *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
     */
    
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = '<?php the_permalink(); ?>';
        this.page.identifier = '<?php echo get_the_ID();?>';
        this.page.title = '<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>';
        this.page.remote_auth_s3 = "<?php echo sprintf('%s %s %s', $message, sb_dsq_hmacsha1($message . ' ' . $timestamp, DISQUS_SECRET_KEY), $timestamp) ?>";
     this.page.api_key = "<?php echo DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY; ?>";
    };
    
    (function () {

  var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;

  dsq.src = '//{insert your forum here}.disqus.com/embed.js';

  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);

  })();
</script>
```

4. Run your site and see disqus config render:
   [image]
   Copy remote_auth_s3 and paste into https://disqus.com/api/sso/ to check the result.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Disqus accounts are a separate entity from WordPress accounts on a particular site.

Users can use the same Disqus account to comment on multiple sites, while the WP accounts are usually exclusive to a particular site.

Comment: it means users on my WP site cannot login once instead of twice to leave the comment?

Comment: Nope. But they can use the same Disqus account on other site than yours.

Comment: I really confusing about your means :( This is the first time i work with Disqus, so if you can explain it more detail step by step how do users login once on WP site, i'm so grateful

Comment: They simply can't login once for a WordPress site and for using Disqus comments. They'd have to login twice.

Comment: If this is an important requirement then I'd recommend not using Disqus comments plugin. WordPress comes with it's own comment system and using it would not require the users to login twice.